# Не работает всплывающее окно,при наведение на картинку

Tags: javascript, html, css

когда навожу на картинку не работает всплывающее окно,tooltip

```js
 var cvs=document.getElementById("canvas"); 
var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d"); 


  var im2a19=new Image(); 

im2a19.src="https://mobimg.b-cdn.net/pic/v2/gallery/111x185/abstrakciya-fon-40429.jpg"; 
im2a19.id='m124';
im2a19.setAttribute("data-tooltip","Количество"+"\r\n"+"очков");
$(im2a19).on("click", function() { 


  
});
 document.body.appendChild(im2a19);
```

```css
  #m124{
   position: absolute;
   top: 100px;
   left: 100px;
  }
  [data-tooltip]:before,
[data-tooltip]:after {
    
  
  
  
  opacity: 0;
  

}


[data-tooltip]:before {
  font:18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 150%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-left: -80px;
  padding: 7px;
  width: 160px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #000;
  background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 20%, 0.9);
  color: #fff;
  content: attr(data-tooltip);
  text-align: center;
  
  line-height: 1.2;
}


[data-tooltip]:after {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 150%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5px solid #000;
  border-top: 5px solid hsla(0, 0%, 20%, 0.9);
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}


[data-tooltip]:hover:before,
[data-tooltip]:hover:after {
  visibility: visible;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- jquery -->
 <title></title>


</head>
<body>
 <canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="675"></canvas> 
<script type="text/javascript">


</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Не работает, потому что тэг `img` не может иметь вложенные элементы.

Comment: то есть не как не сделать чтобы работало?

Comment: Сделать можно что угодно, в разумных пределах. Но данное решение, основанное на css не оптимально.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тэг `img` не может иметь вложенные элементы. Соответственно, надо обернуть `img`, и уже на обертку создать тултип.

```js
var cvs = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");


var im2a19 = new Image();
var wrapper = document.createElement('span');
wrapper.appendChild(im2a19);
wrapper.id = 'm124';
wrapper.setAttribute("data-tooltip", "Количество" + "\r\n" + "очков");

im2a19.src = "https://mobimg.b-cdn.net/pic/v2/gallery/111x185/abstrakciya-fon-40429.jpg";

$(im2a19).on("click", function() {



});
document.body.appendChild(wrapper);
```

```css
#m124 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 100px;
}

[data-tooltip]:before,
[data-tooltip]:after {
  opacity: 0;
}

[data-tooltip]:before {
  font: 18px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-left: -80px;
  padding: 7px;
  width: 160px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #000;
  background-color: hsla(0, 0%, 20%, 0.9);
  color: #fff;
  content: attr(data-tooltip);
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

[data-tooltip]:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  width: 0;
  border-top: 5px solid #000;
  border-top: 5px solid hsla(0, 0%, 20%, 0.9);
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  content: " ";
  font-size: 0;
  line-height: 0;
}

[data-tooltip]:hover:before,
[data-tooltip]:hover:after {
  visibility: visible;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100)";
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=100);
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- jquery -->
  <title></title>


</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="1000" height="675"></canvas>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```